# Show that the surface $x^2 + y^2 + z^2=r^2$, $y=\tan(\theta)$ and $z = (x^2+y^2)\tan^2(\gamma)$ are mutually orthogonal.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Show that the surface $x^2 + y^2 + z^2=r^2$, $y=\tan(\theta)$ and $z = (x^2+y^2)\tan^2(\gamma)$ which are coordinate surfaces of the spherical coordinates $r, \theta, \gamma$ are mutually orthogonal.

Usually, when I am dealing with orthogonal surfaces, I take the gradient and show they are both orthogonal. Here,  I do not understand how the last two functions are written. Do I need to convert them into rectangular coordinates?

Comment: I'm going to assume you meant to write $y=\tan(\theta)x$. I'm also going to assume $r,\gamma,$ and $\theta$ are constants and that these surfaces are defined from a Cartesian perspective. 

The intersection of $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$ with $y=\tan(\theta)x$ can be parameterized by $$\vec{r}_{\theta}(\tau)=\Big(\cos(\theta)\cos(\tau),\sin(\theta)\cos(\tau),\sin(\tau)\Big):0\leq \tau <2\pi$$ Moreover, $$\nabla(x^2+y^2+z^2)=\Big<2x,2y,2z\Big>$$ $$\nabla(y-x\tan(\theta))=\Big<-\tan(\theta),1,0\Big>$$

Comment: Evaluate at $\vec{r}_{\theta}(\tau)$ to get $\big<2\cos(\theta)\cos(\tau),2\sin(\theta)\cos(\tau),2\sin(\tau)\big>$ and $\big<-\tan(\theta),1,0\big>$ which are orthogonal. You can proceed in this manner to show the other two pairs of surfaces intersect orthogonally.